# Python - Concating numerous lists with only one variable assigned to all

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dataframe

How do you concat numerous lists altogether into one single list, when there's a collection of lists assigned to only one variable already?

Most online advices has shown two or many variables to concat together, but mine's only a single variable assigned to many lists. I attempted at a nested For-Loop, but resulted in duplications and incoherent lists. Also attempted with extend and append functions with no success. Maybe I should approach this with Data Frame?

Any help is much appreciated. If you have questions, feel free to ask.

Actual Code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import re
from time import sleep
from random import randint

def price():
    baseURL='https://www.apartmentlist.com/ca/redwood-city'
    r=requests.get(baseURL)
    soup=bs(r.content,'html.parser')

    block=soup.find_all('div',class_='css-1u6cvl9 e1k7pw6k0')
    sleep(randint(2,10))


    for properties in block:
        priceBlock=properties.find_all('div',class_="css-q23zey e131nafx0")
        price=[price.text for price in priceBlock]
        strPrice=''.join(price)                      #Change from list to string type
        removed=r'[$]'                               #Select and remove $ characters
        removed2=r'Ask'                              #Select and remove Ask
        removed3=r'[,]'                              #Select and remove comma
        modPrice=re.sub(removed,' ',strPrice)        #Substitute $ for '_'
        modPrice2=re.sub(removed2,' 0',modPrice)     #Substitute Ask for _0
        modPrice3=re.sub(removed3,'',modPrice2)      #Eliminate space within price
        segments=modPrice3.split()                   #Change string with updates into list, remain clustered
        
        for inserts in segments: 
            newPrice=[inserts]                       #Returns values from string to list by brackets. 
            print(newPrice)
        

price()
```

Actual Output:

```
#After executing the program
['2157']
['2805']
['0']
['1875']
['2800']
['2265']
['2735']
['3985']
...
...
```

Attempt for:

```
['2157', '2805', '0', '2800',...] # all the while assigned to a single variable.
```

Again, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please post your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue in your code is that the "for inserts in segments" loop only takes each price, puts it in its own list, then output the list with only 1 content. So, you need to add all prices to the same list, then after the loop output it.

In your case you can use a list comprehension like this to achieve what you want:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import re
from time import sleep
from random import randint

def price():
    baseURL='https://www.apartmentlist.com/ca/redwood-city'
    r=requests.get(baseURL)
    soup=bs(r.content,'html.parser')

    block=soup.find_all('div',class_='css-1u6cvl9 e1k7pw6k0')
    sleep(randint(2,10))

    result = []
    for properties in block:
        priceBlock=properties.find_all('div',class_="css-q23zey e131nafx0")
        price=[price.text for price in priceBlock]
        strPrice=''.join(price)                      #Change from list to string type
        removed=r'[$]'                               #Select and remove $ characters
        removed2=r'Ask'                              #Select and remove Ask
        removed3=r'[,]'                              #Select and remove comma
        modPrice=re.sub(removed,' ',strPrice)        #Substitute $ for '_'
        modPrice2=re.sub(removed2,' 0',modPrice)     #Substitute Ask for _0
        modPrice3=re.sub(removed3,'',modPrice2)      #Eliminate space within price
        segments=modPrice3.split()                   #Change string with updates into list, remain clustered
        result += [insert for insert in segments]
    print(result)

price()
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I didn't know I can use the += with the list comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

(Hopefully I understood the problem)

If each of the sublists is a variable, you can do one of the following to convert them into a single list:

```
a = ['2157']
b = ['2805']
c = ['0']
d = ['1875']
e = ['2800']
f = ['2265']
g = ['2735']
h = ['3985']

#Pythonic Way
test = [i[0] for i in [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h]]
print(test)

#Detailed Way
check = []
for i in a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h:
    check.append(i[0])
print(check)
```

If your function creates lists, then you would just modify the for loops to reference your function:

```
#Pythonic Way
test = [i[0] for i in YOUR_FUNCTION()]
print(test)

#Detailed Way
check = []
for i in YOUR_FUNCTION():
    check.append(i[0])
print(check)
```

Comment: You understood the problem. My function's for loop was the cause of number lists being established instead of a list.

Comment: Got it. I see the accepted solution uses the same tactic. Always keep list comprehensions in your pocket. They are life savers (dictionary comprehensions are powerful too!). Glad it worked out for you :)

Answer (score 0):

> How do you concat numerous lists altogether into one single list, when there's a collection of lists assigned to only one variable already?

In Python, it's common to flatten a list of lists either with a list comprehension or `itertools.chain`.

```py
from itertools import chain

prices = [
    ['2157'],
    ['2805'],
    ['0'],
    ['1875'],
    ['2800'],
    ['2265'],
    ['2735'],
    ['3985'],
    ]

# list comprehension
[x for row in prices for x in row]
>>> ['2157', '2805', '0', '1875', '2800', '2265', '2735', '3985']

# itertools.chain will return a generator like object
chain.from_iterable(prices)
>>> <itertools.chain at 0x7f01573076a0>

# if you want a list back call list
list(chain.from_iterable(prices))
>>> ['2157', '2805', '0', '1875', '2800', '2265', '2735', '3985']
```

---

For your code above the `price` function is only printing output and not returning an object.  You could have the function create an empty list and add to the list each time you loop through the properties.  Then return the list.

```py
def price():
    # web scrape code

    new_price = []
    for properties in block:
        # processing code
        
        new_price += [x for x in segments]
    return chain.from_iterable(new_prices)
```

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your help!